# ChannelSftp: create new or temporary file

Tags: java, sftp, remote-server, jsch

I am currently using JSch to access some files using SFTP and I also need to perform some changes in each file once it is on the remote server.

I am able to access and read the files using `ChannelSftp` but I would like to create a temporary file while in this remote directory as well. I cannot see a way to do this. I have the ability to make directories and remove files, but not create an empty file? Is this something you can do using `ChannelSftp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put an arbitrary file from an InputStream: `put(InputStream src, String dst)`. You can upload an empty file with that as follows:

```
put( new ByteArrayInputStream( "".getBytes() ), "tempfile");
```

Comment: thank you this has been torturing me for like a day and a half!